# string index out of bounds exception, on an if else statement

Tags: java

The problem code is below, if you need the entire main method to help me, please ask. The code complies but does not run as expected. I am trying to make the code report back an exclamation mark if the number is out of bounds/larger than the last position of the source text, which is a string the user inputs, so the length cannot be predefined. Exception is 'StringIndexOutOfBoundsException'

TDLR num is an int, sourcetext is a string, both are inputs. Exception: when code should output an '!' instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner sc;
        int  result, num= 0, end = -2, temp, infolost, count;
        String word, sourcetext, answer, space= " ";
        String sourcetext2, temp2;
        char input, result2, chalost;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter sourcetext");
        sourcetext = sc.nextLine(); // user inputs source text
        sourcetext = sourcetext.toLowerCase(); // converts sourcetext into lowercase                      
        System.out.print("Would you like to 1 encrypt, or 2 decrypt?");
        answer = sc.next(); // user inputs choice

        if (answer.equals("1")||(answer.equals("encrypt"))) {

            System.out.println("Please enter at least one word to encrypt");
            word = sc.next();   // user inputs one word

            for (int i= 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
                temp = sourcetext.indexOf(word.charAt(i)); // uses index to convert char  positions int num
                System.out.print(space + temp + space);          
            }
            System.out.print(space + end); 
        }
        else if (answer.equals("2")||(answer.equals("decrypt"))) {

            System.out.println("Please enter digits, with one space between each. End  with -2");                 
            while (num > -2) {  
                num = sc.nextInt(); // num to decrypt
                if (num > -2) {      
                    result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num); // num converted into characters
                    System.out.print(result2);
                } else if (num > sourcetext.length()) {
                     System.out.print("!");
                } else if (num<0) {
                     System.out.print("end");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post complete code `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you are trying to access index that is not in range of your string.

Comment: You need to provide full code, possibly with stack trace.

Comment: You need to learn to interpret a stack trace and to use a debugger, rather than asking us to debug your code for you.

Comment: what do you expect at: `sourcetext.charAt(-1)` ??

Comment: crap didn't mean to edit that in there was just experimenting with something... fixed now

Comment: Downvoted, coz it took me hell of a time to properly indent all the mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could lead to an `IndexOutOfBounds`Exception - since `-1` is greater than `-2` - but still out of bounds...

```
if (num > -2){      
    result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num); // num converted into characters
    System.out.print(sourcetext.indexOf(num));
}
```

Edit: Unless the users input is `-2` - the first `if`-Statement will always run... You probably need to re-work the logic there.

Edit2: If `num` is `-1` `sourcetext.charAt(num);` leads to an `IndexOutOfBounds`. Do something like

```
if(num == -2) {
    System.out.print("end");
} else if (num >= 0 && num < sourcetext.lenght()) {
    // index ok
    result2 = sourcetext.charAt(num); // num converted into characters
    System.out.print(result2);
} else {
    // index out of bounds
    System.out.print("!");
}
```

Comment: Can you say this in a differen't way, I'm having trouble understanding this. I want the first if statement to always run unless the answer is -2? Incase you didn't see the edit, this >>> System.out.print(sourcetext.indexOf(num));<<< was a mistake, it is now >>> System.out.print(result2);

Comment: I'm too new to upvote your answer, but it worked! So the main problem was here>> if(num == -2)<<< yes? I'll play around with the code to see where I went wrong anyway, thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
int stringLength = sourcetext.length();

if (num > stringLength) { 
    System.out.print("!");
} 
else if (num<0) {
    System.out.print("end");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error? It should not be having an OutOfBound since you are just comparing values. BTW: if (answer == 1)||(answer.equals("encrypt"))) { //Use == for the numeric. still reviewing your code, would appreciate an error message.

Comment: The if statement 'else if (answer.equals("2")||(answer.equals("decrypt"))) {' isn't where the error throws, it begins here '  else if (num > sourcetext.length()) {
                     System.out.print("!");' when I attempt to input a number that is greater than the last position of the string sourcetext. E.g sourcetext is "ugly", that is three characters long, if I input 5 an error throws instead of adding an exclamation point.